# Elasticsearch: positive boost when term is not present

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to implement a simple search for products using Elasticsearch.

One of the problems that I'm having is that often search queries have implied terms. For example, consider that when someone types in "lenovo thinkpad battery" they want a battery. However, when someone types in just "lenovo thinkpad" they want a laptop, even though that term doesn't appear in the query.

My solution for this is the following. Manually put together a bunch of related terms. For example, for the computer/laptop category I could have the terms "battery", "keyboard", "power cord", "adapter", "cable", "protection plan" etc. Then, whenever no such term is present in the search query, I positive boost all the results that don't contain those terms.

Is this possible with Elasticsearch?

EDIT:

Example documents

```
{"_source": { "item_title": "lenovo thinkpad white/black" },
 "_source": { "item_title": "lenovo thinkpad battery" }
}
```

Mapping

```
{
    "properties": {
        "item_title": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Query

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "from": 0, 
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "match": {
            "item_title": "lenovo thinkpad"
        }
    }
}
```

Query result:

```
"hits": {
  "total": 2,
  "max_score": 0.2169777,
  "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.2169777,
        "_source": {
           "item_title": "lenovo thinkpad battery"
        }
     },
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2169777,
        "_source": {
           "item_title": "lenovo thinkpad black/white"
        }
     }
  ]
}
```

Notice that the score for these two results is the same. However, since the query "lenovo thinkpad" doesn't contain one of those special terms that I manually picked out, like "battery", I would like documents that don't contain that term to be positive boosted, so that the document with "item_title": "lenovo thinkpad white/black" should have higher score in the query results.

Comment: please consider adding query and mappings for reference to understand your problem more effectively

Comment: @user3775217 done

Answer (score 0):

If I execute the Following Query in my Wikipedia index

```
GET /_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "(Darmstadt)^10 (NOT School)^8",
         "fields": [
            "title^3"
         ],
         "phrase_slop": 3,
         "use_dis_max": true
      }
   }
}
```

I Still get  Darmstadt School in the results further down the list (it comes in the first 10 normally)

If i execute the Following Query

```
GET /_search
{
   "query": {
      "query_string": {
         "query": "(Darmstadt AND SCHOOL )^10 (NOT School)^8",
         "fields": [
            "title^3"
         ],
         "phrase_slop": 3,
         "use_dis_max": true
      }
   }
}
```

I Get Darmstadt School as the First result despite it being in the NOT clause.
So I suggest you do something similar.

Comment: If I want to add more words to the NOT camp, what's the syntax?

Comment: "query": "(Darmstadt AND SCHOOL )^10 (NOT School)^8 (NOT Something1)^8 (NOT Something2)^8"

Comment: Still the key to this is understanding "use_dis_max": true which is IMHO the most important part of the query let a, b,c be boolean and a+b+c is my query in boolean if (a+b+c) is true than my query is successful  in use_dis_max a*c*b>a+b+c>a+b=a+c=a+b>a=b=c and the way elastic search works in that case is trying to match AS MANY documents as it can